# Netbeans Python plugin: Exception: org.python.core.PyException

Tags: python, netbeans

I have Netbeans 8.1 with the Python plugin v. 0.151118

Every time I try to run Python code it gives me this failure in the output window:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: org.python.core.PyException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I can run Java code without any problem. I have tried with the build in sample code for Python (which should work) but it gives the same failure.

I have checked the Python platform manager, and it's pointing on all the files in Python path, Java path. and all the files exist in my folders.

I have tried with this Python code.

```
# To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
# To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Hello World"
```

Comment: Could you add the entire exception trace?

Comment: unfortunately I only see those two lines in the output.